# WPF Datagrid RowHeaderTemplate overwritten by RowHeaderStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my WPF application. I have been trying to add a toggle button to the datagridrowheader, which I have managed to do. The issue I have is trying to style the datagridrowheader. If I leave out the line - RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}" my buttons load up correctly. When I add this line back my buttons do not appear, why is this?

As far as I can see the DG_RowHeader is just styling the row header? I would like to know how I can apply this style to my datagridrowheader and have my toggle button also appearing?

My DataGrid

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}" 
                  x:Name="dataGridOrders" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                  Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}"                                            
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}"              
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                  RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetail}"                      
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Silver"
                  RowHeaderWidth="30"                      
                  Margin="25,5,20,15"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dataGridOrders_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton"                                     
                                  Click="RowHeaderToggleButton_Click"
                                  Cursor="Hand"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

My DataGridRowHeader

```
<!-- Data Grid row with toggle button -->
    <Style x:Key="DG_RowHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGRH_Border"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightGray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My ToggleButton

```
<!-- Toogle Button -->
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Name="rowdetailToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>                             
                        <Path x:Name="DefaultPath"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Data="M0,0 14,7 0,14 Z"
                          Fill="DarkGray"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Margin="6"/>
                        <Path x:Name="CheckedPath"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Data="M0,0 14,0 7,14 Z"
                          Fill="DarkGray"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Margin="6"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="DefaultPath"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedPath"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedPath" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="LightGray" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your forgot to display the content of the `DataGridRowHeader` in the `DG_RowHeader` style, more precisely inside `DGRH_Border`.

You can add a ContentPresenter inside of it :

```
<Border x:Name="DGRH_Border"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    [...]
   <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
</Border>
```

As for the `ToggleButtons`, you need to either :

- specify the style in the `ToggleButton`'s declaration :

(assuming your style was defined using a `x:Key` attribute (your specified `x:Name` instead)) :

```
   <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="rowdetailToggleButton">
```

- set the style as the default style for togglebuttons by removing the `x:Key` attribute :

Either way you need to make sure you resource's dictionary are availables from where the button's declared.

Comment: Hi Franssu I have added that line in but appears to have made no difference - still can't see the toggle buttons?

Comment: I think I forgot ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"

Comment: Ah the toggle buttons now show up but the styling is missing?

Comment: @mHelpMe Updated my answer for your ToggleButton's problem.

Comment: Yes I removed the x:Key attribute and it now works, thanks for your help. The next part of my project is for only some of the rows to have toggle buttons not all of them - I'll post another that under another question now.